# JSON parse Mysql query result in php pdo

Tags: php, web-services, pdo

I am trying to do following

```
$statement = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM myTable');
$statement->execute();

if(!($row = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))) 
{
    return false;
}

$conn = null;
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    throw $e;
    return false;
}       

return  return json_encode(array('Result'=>$row);
```

Works and fetches all entries in a table make then JSON Array and send them,

However I want to make a query where selected ids must be send in a JSON Array

E.g 10, 20, 30

I assume that this will be done in a For loop perhaps

```
$statement = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE id = :id');
$statement->bindParam(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$statement->execute();

$row = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)))
```

Now suppose i have id's = 10,20,30 i want to append all of them in a JSON Array How can i do that?

just like  `return json_encode(array('Result'=>$row);`

Edited Code

```
    function GetMyMembers() 
    {
        $myId = trim($_REQUEST['myId']);

        try {
            $conn = $this->GetDBConnection();

            $statement = $conn->prepare('SELECT valId FROM memList WHERE myId=:myId' );
            $statement->bindParam(':myId', $myId, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $statement->execute();

            if(!($row = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))) 
            {
                return false;
            }

// $row contains ALL THE ID'S

            $placeholders = str_repeat('?,', count($row));
            $placeholders = substr($placeholders, 0, -1);
            $sql = "SELECT id, * FROM players WHERE id IN ($placeholders)";
            $statement = $conn->prepare($sql);
            $statement->execute($row);
            $rows = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC|PDO::FETCH_GROUP);

            $conn = null;
        } catch(PDOException $e) {
            throw $e;
            return false;
        }       
        return $rows;
    }
```

Comment: you need to be more certain in expressing your wishes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ids = array(1,2,3);
$placeholders = str_repeat('?,', count($ids));
$placeholders = substr($placeholders, 0, -1);
$sql = "SELECT id, * FROM table WHERE id IN ($placeholders)";
$sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$sth->execute($ids);
$rows = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC|PDO::FETCH_GROUP);
echo json_encode(array('Result' => $rows));
```

Based on additional comments:
Best option:

```
$sql = '
SELECT *
FROM table1 AS t1
INNER JOIN table2 t2
ON  t2.foreign_key = t1.id
';
```

or

```
$sql = 'SELECT id FROM table1';
$sth = $dbh->prepare($sth);
$sth->execute();
$ids = $sth->fetchColumn();
//next look above
```

Comment: ($row = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) i have this code to get list of all entries which will give me ids, now to make $ids = array(1,2,3); how will i do that? please point that out too

Comment: I'm confused, you need only id's from query ?

Comment: no, i am getting ids from another table, since i was hoping to use a for loop but here u used array(1,2,3), how to make my id list like this

Comment: as I understood: you have data from `table1`, and you need fetch data from `table2` where `table2.foreign_key in (table1.id, table1.id, ...)`. Correct ?

Answer (score 1):

```
$statement = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM myTable');
$statement->execute();
$data = array();
while($row = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))) 
{
    $data[$row['id']] = $row;
}
return json_encode(array('Result'=>$data));
```

Btw, using raw API is not convenient. With Database abstraction library your code can be as short as 2 following lines:

```
$data = $db->getInd("id",'SELECT * FROM myTable');
return json_encode(array('Result'=>$data));
```

**Edit:**
if you have an array of ids, you need more complex code

```
$ids  = array(1,2,3);
$data = array();
$statement = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE id = :id');
foreach ($ids as $id) {
    $statement->bindValue(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $statement->execute();
    $data[] = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
}
return json_encode(array('Result'=>$data));
```

But while using Database abstraction library, there will be the same 2 lines:

```
$data = $db->getAll('SELECT * FROM myTable where id IN (?a)', $ids);
return json_encode(array('Result'=>$data));
```

**Edit2:**
if you need ids only

```
$statement = $conn->prepare('SELECT id FROM myTable');
$statement->execute();
$data = array();
while($row = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))) 
{
    $data[] = $row['id'];
}
return json_encode(array('Result'=>$data));
```

while using Database abstraction library, it's still 2 lines:

```
$ids = $db->getCol('SELECT id FROM myTable');
return json_encode(array('Result'=>$ids));
```

Comment: ($row = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) i have this code to get list of all entries which will give me ids, now to make $ids = array(1,2,3); how will i do that? please point that out too –

Comment: didn't get my point, with this above i am getting ids first then need to make a query to get entries of these ids, so my question now was $row = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) Conversion to  $ids  = array(1,2,3);